# Sorting algorithm with no repeat comparisons?

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic

I have a list of items to sort manually. My method is to pop a dialogue box to the user which says *"which item is better"*, they click on the better one and this equates to a `a>b` comparison in code.

Using .NET's arraylist which [implements sorting using QuickSort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.sort?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=the%20QuickSort%20algorithm.-,The%20QuickSort%20algorithm,-is%20a%20comparison) I'm finding the same 2 items are often compared to one another.

Since comparison is extremely slow (manual) is there an algorithm like quicksort but which remembers the result of a comparison of 2 items?

Comment: Can't you just wrap your comparison method `askUser(x,y)` inside a method `compare(x,y)` that only calls `askUser` if necessary, and stores the result of the comparison in a local map `(item, item) -> bool` so it can be reused?

Comment: Although, if you're interested in research paper from the domain of operational research, see https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=ranking+pairwise+comparison and in particular [Preference learning and ranking by pairwise comparison](http://dagstuhl.sunsite.rwth-aachen.de/volltexte/2014/4550/pdf/dagrep_v004_i003_p001_s14101.pdf)

Comment: merge sort works